# GLSL Shader going black when I try to sample a texture

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader, texture-mapping

I render a triangle strip this way, and with basic bypass shaders all is working fine:
EDIT:
I added TextCoords and modified the shaders , I keep getting the same result, my 3d objects are going black!

**UPDATED CODE**:

```
// Dibuixem tots els prismes
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for(i=0;i<num_elems;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<num_vertices;j++) {

            glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(a+j*2));
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); 
            glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(a+j*2+1));
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); 
            glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(b+j*2));
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); 
            glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(b+j*2+1));
        }

        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(a));
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(a+1));
        glNormal3fv((GLfloat *)(b));
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); 
        glVertex3fv((GLfloat *)(b+1));
        a+=face_size;
        b+=face_size;
    }
    glEnd();
```

And I am trying to attach a texture to my shaders, but I can't figure out how to pass the texture.

I create and add the texture to my program this way. Texture data is verified
array with format `unsigned char data[imageSize];`:

```
   GLuint textureID;
   glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // Texture unit 0
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_BGR, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

This is what I read in another posts with the same issue and I added to my code after compiling my shaders and generating my program without errors.
Tutorials tend to dismiss this information (how you say to your shader the name and location of your binded texture).

```
GLuint t1Location = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "tex1");
glUniform1i(t1Location, 0);
```

And my shaders **UPDATED CODE**:

```
#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader
const char* vert = GLSL
(
    110,

    varying vec4 position;
    varying vec3 normal;
    varying out vec4 texCoord;
    varying vec2 coord;
    void main()
    {
        position    = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        normal      = normalize( gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal.xyz );
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        coord       = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
    } 
);


    


const char* frag  = GLSL
(
    110,
        
    uniform sampler2D tex1;
    varying vec4 position;
    varying vec3 normal;
    varying vec2 coord;
    
    void main()
    {
         gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, coord);
    } 
);
```

EDIT2:

I am setting up gl this way:(maybe something is conflicting with my texture shader, but I don't think so!

```
 /* set up depth-buffering */
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

   glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
   glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST);

   /* set up lights */
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

   GLfloat lightpos[]   = { 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
   GLfloat lightcolor[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
   GLfloat ambcolor[]   = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };

   glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,ambcolor);

   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
   glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

   glEnable  (GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
   glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,lightpos);
   glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,ambcolor);
   glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,lightcolor);
   glLightfv (GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,lightcolor);
   glLightf  (GL_LIGHT0,GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION,0.2);
   glLightf  (GL_LIGHT0,GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION,0.0);
   glLightf  (GL_LIGHT0,GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION,1.0);
   glEnable  (GL_LIGHT0);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Replacing `gl_FragColor` by a flat color is working fine.
I know maybe is related to `coord` parameter but I am trying all the stuff I found and nothing is working for me.

Comment: Do you provide texture coordinates? (`glTexCoord*`)? Since you are already using shaders, you should stop using ancient code and stick to modern OpenGL with VBO, VAO, etc. Also: What does the `GLSL(` macro do?

Comment: I know that, but the project is inherited and I have not time to rebuild to vertex buffers at this moment... 

I tried to pass varying out vec4 texCoord; to my vertex shader
assign texCoord    = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
I understand that there is a lack of info about what are the texture coordinares to map, how I should do that? 

The macro is only adding the header and version to the shader code. This is working fine!

Comment: You have to specify texture coordinates similar to normals on the cpu side using one of the [`glTexCoord*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) methods.

Comment: You have to use [**`gl_MultiTexCoord0`**](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php) which is a bulit in uniform as `gl_Vertex` or `gl_Normal`. It is only allowed in the vertex shader, so you have to pass it to the fragment shader like `position` and `normal`. And you have to use [**`glTexCoord2f`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) similar like `glVertex3fv` and `glNormal3fv`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I enabled GL_TEXTURE_2D with the same result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal texture format `GL_BGR` is not valid. `GL_BGR` is a valid for the format of the source texture, but the internal representation has to be `GL_RGB`.
See [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

Adapt your code like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

See the Khronos reference page [GLAPI/glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D) which says:

> To define texture images, call [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). The arguments describe the parameters of the texture image, such as height, width, width of the border, level-of-detail number (see `glTexParameter`), and number of color components provided. The last three arguments describe how the image is represented in memory.
>   
>   `format`​ determines the composition of each element in data​. It can assume one of these symbolic values:
>   
>   `GL_BGR`:
>   Each element is an RGB triple. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 1 for alpha. Each component is clamped to the range [0,1].

Comment: I changed that because this line was throwing an SIGSEGV(11).
Now, changed back again is throwing again the invalid memory reference, 
So I have to parse my char array to a float array with values between 0 and 1 to be accepted?

Comment: @Charles No, this is what OpenGL should do.

Comment: OK, I will try to generate some textures manually and see what happens.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Charles On of the liks in the answer was wrong - [GLAPI/glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D). Did you try `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);` for debug reasons?

Comment: Now kinda works! The memory error was caused due going out of width and heigth, it is related to the ALPHA channel, when I exported the texture I deleted the alpha channel, but somehow that did not work. But now I face that:

this works:

    `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, width*3/4, height*3/4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

this crashes:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, width*3/4 +1, height*3/4 +1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`


`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA, width*3/4 +1, height*3/4 +1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

Comment: @Charles Note, `width` should be the number of pixel in a row and `height` should be the number of rows of the image. For a tightly packed BGR or RGB image the required size of the image plane (in bytes) is `width * height * 3`.

Comment: Yes, I was doing that, so I am lost. Checked that the image has not alpha channel but the trick of process width and height as with alpha worked so width and height from BMP header are not coherent with the numer of channels (3)... I will resolve this deeper when I have time.  

Anyway thanks a lot @Rabbid! I appreciate all your help.